# Why isn't my computed property firing when the listener is changed?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple ArrayController with a filteredContent computed property that lets me slice n' dice the array of ember objects. I have an interval property that when changed, I'd like to re-calculate the computed property.

Yet with the below, my filteredContent property doesn't seem to fire when I "set" the interval

```
App.FilterController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    interval: 15,
    filterAvailable: function(event) {
        var selected = event.target.selectedIndex;
        var value = this.get('content')[selected].get('id');
        this.set('interval', value);
    },
    filteredContent: function() {
        var cleaned = this.get('content').toArray().filter(function(apt) {
            return apt.get('id') === null;
        });
        var sorted = cleaned.sort(function(a, b) {
            return Ember.compare(new Date(get(a, 'start')), new Date(get(b, 'start')));
        });
        return sorted;
    }.property("interval", "content.@each")
});
```

In my template I have a select with a simple changeBinding that kicks off the "filter available" method

```
  {{view Ember.Select
  changeBinding="controller.filterAvailable"}}
```

Comment: What is using filteredContent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to bed, but if nothing is dependent on (aka observing) `filteredContent` then it doesn't recalculate.

Adding it to the template does satisfy the requirement.

You may check that `this` is the controller, and not the view, or something else, i'm not sure how filterAvailable is being called.

Yeah, that was my suspicion, the context of filterAvailable when executed is the select view, you'll need to get the controller and set on it.  So currently you are setting a property `interval` on the select view, instead of what would be expected.

```
filterAvailable: function(event) {
    var selected = event.target.selectedIndex;
    var value = this.get('content')[selected].get('id');
    // the controller backing the select view is your Filter Controller
    this.set('controller.interval', value);
},
```

Comment: yes- here is how I'm using it in my template {{#each appointment in controller.filteredContent}}

Comment: how is filterAvailable called?

Comment: Could we cleanup the answer and comments so others who find this get a clear picture of what I did wrong/ and what you suggested to fix it?

Comment: Definitely, I'm one handed typing right now, so feel free to modify at will